# How to align piecewise functions?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, arrays

I have two piecewise functions defined like this:

```
\begin{align*}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      i = x^2 + y^2 \\ 
      j = a^2 + b^2 \\
    \end{array}
  \right.
\\
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      i = 1 \\
      j = 2 \\
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{align*}
```

The problem is that they're not aligned. How do I align them?
[image]

Comment: Place an `&` before the `\left\{` of each.

Comment: It would be better to provide a complete MWE, from `\begin{document}` to `\end{document}` with all needed packages. This way it's easier to test your code and provide a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quick fix is a simple addition of two ampersands before opening the large curly brackets. In the `amsmath` `align` environment, along with the starred version, the ampersand tells LaTeX what elements should be aligned.

```
\begin{align*}
  &\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      i = x^2 + y^2 \\ 
      j = a^2 + b^2 \\
    \end{array}
  \right.
\\
  &\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
      i = 1 \\
      j = 2 \\
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Perhaps the following code using `split` is a little better to align the `=` signs, although it's a matter of taste. The ampersand once again allows you to align the brackets on one level, and the equality signs on the level down. This is done inside the starred `equation` environment to allow `split` to be used, which is provided by the `amsmath` package.

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
  &\left\{
    \begin{split}
      i &= x^2 + y^2 \\ 
      j &= a^2 + b^2 \\
    \end{split}
  \right.
\\
  &\left\{
    \begin{split}
      i &= 1 \\
      j &= 2 \\
    \end{split}
  \right.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

If the reduced space between the bracket and the equations bothers you in this version, you can insert horizontal space, for example with `\,` or with `\hspace{2pt}` just after the `\left\{` of each group. Using `\;` spacing in this solution gives the final version of this code:

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
  &\left\{\;
    \begin{split}
      i &= x^2 + y^2 \\ 
      j &= a^2 + b^2 \\
    \end{split}
  \right.
\\
  &\left\{\;
    \begin{split}
      i &= 1 \\
      j &= 2 \\
    \end{split}
  \right.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: Would you also explain why? Perhaps suggesting `cases` instead of `split`.

Comment: @egreg: Good point. I added some more detail to explain what the ampersands are for.

Comment: @egreg: Cases has been suggested at the time of this comment in Gonzalo's answer.

Comment: @egreg: In addition, cases behave badly when you try to align them on the equalities.

Answer (score 7):

To simplify, in this case, you can use two `cases` environments inside a `align*` using `&` to align both structures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  &\begin{cases}
      \rlap{$i$}\phantom{j} = x^2 + y^2 \\ 
      j = a^2 + b^2
    \end{cases}\\
  &\begin{cases}
      \rlap{$i$}\phantom{j} = 1 \\
      j = 2
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cases behave badly when you try to align them on the `=` symbol.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: I know; that's why I said in my answer *in this case*. In this concrete example there's no need to use `&` for the equal symbol.

Comment: To be fair, *in this case* is a little ambiguous.

Comment: @MarkS.Everitt: in fact; I've just noticed a little misalignment issue at the = symbols; I've updated my answer to correct this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way of aligning these two components:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{r@{\;}l}
      i &= x^2 + y^2 \\ 
      j &= a^2 + b^2
    \end{array}
  \right.
\\
  \left\{
    \begin{array}{r@{\;}l}
      i &= \rlap{1}\phantom{x^2 + y^2} \\
      j &= \rlap{2}\phantom{a^2 + b^2}
    \end{array}
  \right.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

You didn't use any column separation `&` in your `array`. I've inserted that at the alignment point (before `=`). Otherwise you would have noticed the difference in the unaligned equality signs due to different widths of `i` and `j`. I also changed your `ll` column specification into `r@{\;}l` to `r`ight-align the left-hand side, and `l`eft-align the right-hand side, plus add the appropriate spacing `\;` between the relational operator.

The use of the `\rlap` (short for `r`ight over`lap`) and `\phantom` (leaves space without typesetting) combination is aimed at making the lower `array` have the same width as the upper one, thereby establishing the appropriate horizontal spacing.

Comment: Quite complicated a solution, isn't it? A `&` before `\left\{` is all that's needed.

Comment: @egreg: Nope. With *only* that, the equal signs won't line up. Also, the left braces spacing is slightly modified in split.

Comment: The `&` would align the braces so the `\phantom` commands become unnecessary, taking also into account that the two left hand side terms are the same in both arrays. Whether to align these equals signs is just a matter of personal taste.